# Google Spreadsheet ARRAYFORMULA() with INDIRECT() and ADDRESS()

Tags: google-sheets, range, array-formulas, excel-indirect

I have a sheet where I paste new orders down, like this:
[As you can se, the orders are composed by products a, b, c, d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jZjb.png)

In other columns, I have array formulas to identify the limits of the orders, I mean, the number of the row where the order stars and ends (on the second picture link you can see what I mean).

Well, now I want to make an arrayformula that allows me to search, order by order, the quantity of products a,b,c,d. I made a function that works fine on a cell:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H$1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS($F2,1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS($G2,2)),2,0))
```

But, when I use it with an ARRAYFORMULA, it doesn't work, because it has INDIRECT function to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H$1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS($F2:F,1)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS($G2:G,2)),2,0)))
```

The result of what I need, should complete the cells like this:

[But using an array formula instead of copy-pasting the formula cell by cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjfi2.png)

I thank and hope someone can help me solving this!

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? With the screenshot you posted I cannot recreate anything. Thanks

Comment: Robin, Thanks for your interest. here, I am sharing the google worksheet, please, let me know if you need more info:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQubQItv29jLiTcNNmomrr4aOGPbxlueVONVZ9drFww/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: TBH this will be much easier to solve with Google Apps script, are you open to that?

Comment: Sure Robin, I am open to solve it with Google Apps script, doesn't matter. Once again, thanks